# What is the AWS CodeStar project URL for connecting to JIRA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codestar

AWS CodeStar enabled integration with JIRA. You can go to AWS CodeStar > Extensions > add extension and follow instructions to integrate with your JIRA application.

However, the "AWS CodeStar project URL" that is provided is in the format:

```
https://awscodestar-yourcodestarprojectname.com
```

This URL is not valid - this domain name includes your CodeStar project name, which is not registered. The correct URL is probably a subdomain of some AWS CodeStar domain. Does anyone know what is the correct URL to use when integrating with JIRA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using https://codestar.us-east-1.amazonaws.com instead of the CodeStar project URL provided in the connection instructions.  For endpoints for other regions see the CodeStar endpoints table in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#codestar_region.